# При нажатии на иконку перейти к другой секции

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, css3

Как при нажатии на иконку стрелки перейти к следующей секции с текстом?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

section.title {
  background-color: coral;
}

section.text {
  background-color: white;
}

h1,
p {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1) opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="title">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <a href="#" class="arrow" address="true"></a>
</section>
<section class="text">
  <p>Текст</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"], a[href^="."]').click( function(e){
     var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href');
        if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) {
     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500);
        }
     e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

section.title {
  background-color: coral;
}

section.text {
  background-color: white;
}

h1,
p {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1) opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="title">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <a href="#text" class="arrow" address="true"></a>
</section>
<section id="text" class="text">
  <p>Текст</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```js
const btnArrow = document.querySelector(".arrow");
const sectionText = document.querySelector(".text");

function scrollTo(element) {
  window.scroll({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    left: 0,
    top: element.offsetTop
  });
}

btnArrow.addEventListener('click', () => {
  scrollTo(sectionText);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

section.title {
  background-color: coral;
}

section.text {
  background-color: white;
}

h1,
p {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1) opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="title">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <a href="#" class="arrow" address="true"></a>
</section>
<section class="text">
  <p>Текст</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.arrow').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('section.text').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

section.title {
  background-color: coral;
}

section.text {
  background-color: white;
}

h1,
p {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -16px;
  display: block;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 2px solid #FFF;
  background-size: 14px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  animation: bounce 2s infinite 2s;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transition: all .2s ease-in;
  transform: scale(1) opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
  transition: all .5s ease-in 3s;
}

.arrow:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  left: calc(50% - 7px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  display: block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  content: "";
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 0px 0 2px 2px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  100%,
  20%,
  50%,
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  60% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-5px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-5px);
    transform: translateY(-5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="title">
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <a href="#" class="arrow" address="true"></a>
</section>
<section class="text">
  <p>Текст</p>
</section>
```

Comment: тут даже jquery не нужен ...

Comment: да нее ..ты не понял __ решётку и scroll-behaviour по моему можно

Comment: токо минус в том что якорь остаётся в url а так классно работает

Comment: разумеется _ я же говорил о примере без js/jquery а на jquery Вы сделали e.preventDefault() что останавливает стандартное поведение